# How file lookup work in Docker container

Tags: docker, unionfs

According to [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/), every Dockerfile instruction create a layer, and all the layers are kept when you create new image based on an old one. Then when I create my own image, I might have hundreds of layers involved because of the recursive inherit of layers of base image.

In my understand, file lookup in container work this way:

1. process want to access file `a`, lookup starts from the container layer(thin w/r layer) .
2. UnionFS check whether this layer have a record for it (have it or marked as deleted). If yes, return it or say not found respectively, ending the lookup. If no, pass the task to the layer below.
3. the lookup end at the bottom layer.

If that is the way, consider a file that resides in the bottom layer and unchanged by other layers, `/bin/sh` maybe, would need going through all the layers to the bottom. Though the layers might be very light-weight, a lookup still need 100x time than a regular one, noticeable. But from my experience, Docker is pretty fast, almost same as a native OS. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all thanks to [UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) and [Union mounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount)!

Straight from wikipedia:

> It allows files and directories of separate file systems, known as
>   branches, to be **transparently overlaid**, forming a single coherent file
>   system.

And from an interesting [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/312641/):

> In the kernel, the filesystems are stacked in order of their mount
>   sequence, the first mounted filesystem is at the bottom of the mount
>   stack, and the latest mount is at the top of the stack. Only the files
>   and directories of the top of the mount stack are visible. With union
>   mounts, directory entries from the lower filesystems are merged with
>   the directory entries of upper filesystem, thus making a logical
>   combination of all mounted filesystems. Files with the same name in a
>   lower filesystem are masked, as the upper one takes precedence.

So it doesn't "go through layers" in the conventional sense (e.g one at a time) but rather it knows (at any given time) which file resides on which disk.

Doing this in the filesystem layer also means none of the software has to worry about where the file resides, it knows to ask for `/bin/sh` and the filesystem knows where to get it.

More info can be found in this [webinar](https://blog.docker.com/2015/10/docker-basics-webinar-qa/).

### So to answer your question:

> Where am I wrong?

You are thinking that it has to look through the layers one at a time while it doesn't have to do that. (UnionFS is awesome!)

Answer (score 2):

To add to the correct prior answer, copy-on-write (CoW) and union filesystem implementors want to have near-native performance, so, of course, have tuned their implementations and "API" to have best possible lookup/filesystem performance.

That said, it's good to be aware that Docker does not operate on top of only a single 'type' of union/CoW filesystem, but has a small array of available options, with defaults depending on the Linux distro on which it is installed.

AUFS and overlay(fs) are the most common, but Docker also supports devicemapper (Red Hat contributed and supported on Fedora/RHEL/CentOS), btrfs, and zfs. I have a [blog post](https://integratedcode.us/2016/08/30/storage-drivers-in-docker-a-deep-dive/) comparing and contrasting the various options that may be of interest.